# How do I create unadorned color bars without a plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to create color bars of the type used by Kenneth Moreland in his excellent paper, ["Diverging Color Maps for Scientific Visualization"](http://www.sandia.gov/~kmorel/documents/ColorMaps/).

They are unadorned and look like this:

[image: color bars]

Any idea how he did this?

Comment: As a colorblind I definitely agree :)

Comment: You could try emailing him `:-)`

Comment: @JohnWickerson Never a bad idea :)

Comment: @percusse I had classmate with deuteranopia. It woke me up to the problem. He had real trouble with a lot of presentation slides, and he couldn't see standard laser pointers at all. Meanwhile, the presenters were always blissfully unaware that some of the audience might not be able to distinguish what they were pointing at.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is a shading.

The only question is where did you get the colormaps? Since you mentioned "plot", I suppose you refer to the tikz library `pgfplots`.

*If* you are given some `pgfplots` colormap on input and you want to show it "unadorned", you can proceed as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={cyanmauve}{color=(cyan) rgb255=(224,176,255)},
}

% convert `hot' -> \result
\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec{cyanmauve}{8cm}\result
% define and use a shading in pgf:
\def\tempb{\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{tempshading}{1cm}}%
% where `\result' is inserted as last argument:
\expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\result}%
\pgfuseshading{tempshading}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not refer to a `pgfplots` colormap and you simply wanted some shading, then you can use

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{colormap}{1cm}{rgb(0.0pt)=(0,1,1); rgb(8cm)=(0.8784,0.6902,0.99998)}
\pgfuseshading{colormap}
\end{document}
```

which has the same output.

References: the `\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec` is documented in the `pgfplots` manual, along with a very detailed instruction how to define `colormaps` (compare its section "Color Maps").

The macro `\pgfdeclare*shading` is explained in all detail in `pgfmanual.pdf`.

Answer (score 10):

An addition to Christian Feuersänger's answer: The key point of Moreland's method is that the interpolation of the colours does not happen in RGB space, but in Msh space, which leads to more uniform colour gradients.

Moreland provides an Excel spreadsheet that calculates these gradients and converts them to RGB. To generate the colormap specification for PGFPlots, you can copy the list of RGB values to a new file `colormap.txt`, say:

```
0   152 190
37  156 190
55  159 191
69  162 191
81  165 191
92  168 190
102 170 190
112 172 190
121 174 189
130 176 188
138 177 187
146 179 186
153 179 185
160 180 184
167 180 183
174 180 181
180 180 180
184 179 175
187 177 169
190 175 164
192 172 158
195 169 152
196 166 146
198 163 140
199 159 134
200 155 128
200 150 122
200 146 116
200 141 110
199 136 104
198 131 98
197 125 92
195 119 86
```

and then run the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{printf "rgb255=(%s,%s,%s) ", $1,$2,$3}' < colormap.txt
```

which will give you the following string:

```
rgb255=(0,152,190) rgb255=(37,156,190) rgb255=(55,159,191) rgb255=(69,162,191) rgb255=(81,165,191) rgb255=(92,168,190) rgb255=(102,170,190) rgb255=(112,172,190) rgb255=(121,174,189) rgb255=(130,176,188) rgb255=(138,177,187) rgb255=(146,179,186) rgb255=(153,179,185) rgb255=(160,180,184) rgb255=(167,180,183) rgb255=(174,180,181) rgb255=(180,180,180) rgb255=(184,179,175) rgb255=(187,177,169) rgb255=(190,175,164) rgb255=(192,172,158) rgb255=(195,169,152) rgb255=(196,166,146) rgb255=(198,163,140) rgb255=(199,159,134) rgb255=(200,155,128) rgb255=(200,150,122) rgb255=(200,146,116) rgb255=(200,141,110) rgb255=(199,136,104) rgb255=(198,131,98) rgb255=(197,125,92) rgb255=(195,119,86)
```

That string can then be pasted into Christian's code for generating the colormap:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
colormap={moreland}{
rgb255=(0,152,190) rgb255=(37,156,190) rgb255=(55,159,191) rgb255=(69,162,191) rgb255=(81,165,191) rgb255=(92,168,190) rgb255=(102,170,190) rgb255=(112,172,190) rgb255=(121,174,189) rgb255=(130,176,188) rgb255=(138,177,187) rgb255=(146,179,186) rgb255=(153,179,185) rgb255=(160,180,184) rgb255=(167,180,183) rgb255=(174,180,181) rgb255=(180,180,180) rgb255=(184,179,175) rgb255=(187,177,169) rgb255=(190,175,164) rgb255=(192,172,158) rgb255=(195,169,152) rgb255=(196,166,146) rgb255=(198,163,140) rgb255=(199,159,134) rgb255=(200,155,128) rgb255=(200,150,122) rgb255=(200,146,116) rgb255=(200,141,110) rgb255=(199,136,104) rgb255=(198,131,98) rgb255=(197,125,92) rgb255=(195,119,86)
}
}


\pgfplotscolormaptoshadingspec{moreland}{8cm}\result
\def\tempb{\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{moreland}{1cm}}%
\expandafter\tempb\expandafter{\result}%
\pgfuseshading{moreland}%


\end{document}
```

This results in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jake! My bad: I misunderstood a key point of the question.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: No no, I think your answer does address the key point (how to get a rectangle with a specified colour gradient).

Answer (score 3):

For a simple gradient, one easy way is the  `tcolorbox` package that use TikZ internally:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
[skin=widget,
boxrule=0mm,
arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,
width=5cm, height=3mm,
interior style={
left color=blue!40!white,
right color=red!90!green!65}]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
[skin=widget,
boxrule=0mm,
arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,
width=5cm, height=3mm,
interior style={
left color=green!60!black,
right color=red!85!black}]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Note: As Jake comment, of course this can also obtained using directly  TikZ, but `tcolorbox` have interesting options if this gradient could be used as background of text, tables or images.

A more complex gradient, could be obtained also with TikZ  without using `pgfplots` of the other answers, simply overlapping some fading rectangles:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [blue,path fading=west] (0,0) rectangle (5cm,3mm);
\fill [red,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (5cm,3mm);
\fill [yellow,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,3mm);
\fill [green,path fading=west] (3,0) rectangle (5cm,3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even easier would be to just load `\usepackage{tikz}` and  use `\tikz \fill [left color=green!60!black, right color=red!85!black] (0,0) rectangle (5cm,3mm);` (no need for `tcolorbox` if all one wants is a rectangle), but in order to get the more sophisticated colour gradients described in Moreland's paper, one would need to define a color map or shading like in Christian's answer (where `pgfplots` comes in handy).

Comment: @Jake Oh, I must be a sophisticated gradient. Well, I have already changed the answer, but obviously  without `pgfplots` `:)`. I made the simple gradient with  `tcolorbox` instead of TikZ directly because I used to do something more that empty gradient, but I realize that is made really by TikZ.